# How to include all points into error-less triangulation mesh with scipy.spatial.Delaunay?

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I am testing **scipy.spatial.Delaunay** and not able to solve two issues:

1. the mesh has errors
2. the mesh doesn't include all points

Code and image of plot:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay,delaunay_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
#input_xyz.txt contains 1000 pts in "X Y Z" (float numbers) format
points = np.loadtxt("input_xyz.txt", delimiter=" ", usecols=(0, 1))
tri = Delaunay(points)
delaunay_plot_2d(tri)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As mentioned under **scipy.spatial.Delaunay**:

*"Unless you pass in the Qhull option “QJ”, Qhull does not guarantee that each input point appears as a vertex in the Delaunay triangulation."*

But if I use QJ:

```
tri = Delaunay(points, qhull_options = "QJ")
```

I get Qhull error and if I use QJn (n=some high number):

```
tri = Delaunay(points, qhull_options = "QJ200")
```

to overcome that error the generated mesh looks terrible - triangles all over the place crossing each other.

**How to include all points into error-less triangulation mesh with scipy.spatial.Delaunay?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page for help clarifying this question. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will also help.

Comment: @IanAuld sorry, I thought it is pretty clear, I need find proper parameters (if possible) to run scipy.spatial.Delaunay so each input point appears as a vertex in the Delaunay triangulation and triangles are not crossing each other. When scipy.spatial.Delaunay is run by default it has both of these problems.

Comment: I see you didn't read the links I posted. A proper question for SO will have a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How can we help you without seeing what inputs you are using, the code you have written and what you expect your output is?

Comment: @IanAuld thank you for your advise, is that better now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your data set is not centered. Qhull (used to do the Delaunay triangulation) does not center the data set for you under the default options, so it runs to rounding errors far away from origin.

You can center it yourself before triangulation

```
points -= points.mean(axis=0)
tri = Delaunay(points)
```

Comment: Wow, it works great. I had no idea this could be a problem. Could you please elaborate a bit more what the line for centering the data set literary does?

Comment: Oh I see now, it is centering dataset to origin.