# Scipy Delaunay doesn't create faces for all points

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

When running [Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html#scipy-spatial-delaunay) on a set of four points, I expect at least two triangles to be produced. Instead I am returned only one. How can I have all faces produced?

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
points = [(0, 0, -8), (1, 0, -24), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
triangulation = Delaunay(points)

triangulation.simplices
```

`out: [[3 2 1 0]]`

Visualizing the points and faces produces:

[image]

[The solution by Pv.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868399/how-to-include-all-points-into-error-less-triangulation-mesh-with-scipy-spatial?rq=1) did not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

The result is to be expected.  You have four points in 3-d.  The [n-dimensional "triangulation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#d-dimensional_Delaunay) produced by `Delaunay` is a collection of [simplexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), and a simplex in 3-d is a tetrahedron.  With just four points, the Delaunay triangulation is a single tetrahedron.

The [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) might be what you want.  For that, you can use [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html):

```
In [10]: points = [(0, 0, -8), (1, 0, -24), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]

In [11]: from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

In [12]: h = ConvexHull(points)

In [13]: h.simplices
Out[13]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [3, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

(Of course, with just four points, there is no need to use `ConvexHull` to produce that result.)